# Controlling table with JS

Tags: javascript

I have written a very simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<table id="myTable" border = "1"></table>

<script>

    for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        var tableRow = "<tr>";
        tableRow+= "<td>" + "JS Table" + "</td>";
        tableRow+= "</tr>";        
    }

    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = tableRow;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to generate a table like this code snippet

```
<table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td>JS Table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JS Table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JS Table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JS Table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JS Table</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But it's giving only one row while I have set for loop for 5 times. How to solve this.

I am facing one more problem. If I write javascript in head tag, I don;t get any output & it's saying "document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML" is null. How to rectify it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>      

    <script>

    for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        var tableRow = "<tr>";
        tableRow+= "<td>" + "JS Table" + "</td>";
        tableRow+= "</tr>";        
    }

    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = tableRow;

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="myTable"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: declare `var tableRow` before the loop and remove the `var` keyword inside the loop. Also you need to update the content of the `<table>` only when the dom is ready. So you could put the script tag after the `<table>`

Comment: @Brijesh for your second question: The html code will be invoked line by line, when it occure. When browser reach the line with `document...` the table element does not exists yet. Solution: wrap your Javascript function into events like `onload`or `ondomready`, or place it after your html table.

Comment: Thanks reporter, it help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The problem is that you are overriding your tableRow again and again in the for loop. So, you need to move that outside the for loop. You will need to update your script to

```
var tableRow = ""; // moved outside the loop
for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
    tableRow += "<tr>"; // appending <tr>
    tableRow+= "<td>" + "JS Table" + "</td>";
    tableRow+= "</tr>";        
}

document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = tableRow;
```

**Problem 2**

The issue is coming because you are trying to execute the code before the dom is rendered. Try it wrap it inside the `onload` function i.e.

```
window.onload = function(){
    // your code here
};
```

For reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>      

        <script>
        window.onload = function(){
          
          var tableRow = "";
          for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            tableRow += "<tr>";
            tableRow += "<td>" + "JS Table" + "</td>";
            tableRow += "</tr>";        
          }

          document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = tableRow;
        };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <table id="myTable"></table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var   tableRow=""; 

for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
         tableRow += "<tr>";
        tableRow+= "<td>" + "JS Table" + "</td>";
        tableRow+= "</tr>";   

    }

    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = tableRow;
```

```html
 <table id="myTable"></table>
```